# Configuration system failed to initialize 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config

Firstly, I  searched on the StackOverflow ,also watched all the similar answers but can't find any solution.

**app.conf file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <configSections>
      <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
         <section name="dtaabse.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionstrings>
    <add name="Db" connectionstring="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog =DV login pro; Integrated Security=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
/>
  </connectionstrings>

  <applicationSettings>
    <dtaabse.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="setting" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
    </dtaabse.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

`form.cs` file

```
string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Db"].ConnectionString;
```

Only this line shows the error. Please help me to find this error!

Answer (score 0):

It's case sensitivity. Change `connectionstring` and `connectionstrings` to `connectionString` and `connectionStrings`.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Db" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog =DV login pro; Integrated Security=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    />
 </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: My pleasure. If that's correct, please mark it as answered. Thanks